# Protect iframe from other's and Use One domain for the iframe?

Tags: javascript, url, iframe, redirect, save

hi i want java scripts for Iframe protection and they work only one site like 
iframe site url is **www.iframe.com** and i want to protect on **www.my-mainwebsite.com**

i just want www.iframe.com work only on **www.my-mainwebsite.com** when these iframe code use another site like **www.anothersite.com** they will be redirect to **www.my-mainwebsite.com**

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (top !=self || top.location != "www.iframe.com") {
   top.location=self.location;
}
</script>
```

Here is a quick JavaScript  code that you can use if you want to make sure that no one should be able to show your website in an IFrame.

**Edit1:**

- Added second check in if, if site is not equal to "www.iframe.com"

Comment: thanks but i want one site be able to use this iframe and not others

Comment: I updated code, don't got time for testing, normally it should work

Comment: Owkey, is it possible to rephrase your question cause i don't think i really get your point then (:

Comment: @Mr.Zijkant: shouldn't that be `&&` rather than `||`?